# Keep IBackgroundTask open after closing the UI

Tags: c#, uwp, background-process

I am creating a quite complex program, where I want to make an RGB Controller out of my Arduino. Me being me, if I start to build it on my own, I want it to be perfect. So I made this:

Control the arduino using UWP (Windows Remote Arduino) - done 
Check which application is in use via an sideloaded win32 app - done 
Send this information to the UWP - done

Now this requires you to keep the UI open. So I created a System tray extension. But when done, I stumbled on the last problem: I can't do anything with a UWP when it is not open, and thus the controls for the Arduino stopped working. I figured out that you need to use a Out-Of-Process application (Windows Runtime Component), but the problem is that it closes when I close the UI, the WRC closes with it.

In short, how do I prevent a Windows Runtime Component from closing when the UI does. And if this is not possible, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Sounds like you want a windows service instead, or at least find something like [ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF (unfortunately I don't know if there is anything like that in UWP).

Comment: The system has a separate process to control the Out-of-Process background tasks. We can not control them. The background tasks will be executed automatically when the specific conditions are satisfied. I would suggest that if you just want to send information to UWP app, you could send toast notification with parameters, then when the user tap the toast from action center, you could handle it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts#handling-activation

Comment: Have you looked at ApplicationTrigger? This allows you to trigger a BackgroundTask from your foreground application that will keep running when your app UI gets closed.

Comment: The ApplicationTrigger sounds promising, in fact, I am using it already for the IBackgroundTask (which is closing with the UI). Can you give me an example on how to use this @StefanWickMSFT ?
**Edit:** I get an error when using this trigger with the background task (Which is not in the Task Manager, but the Runtime Broker is), complaining that there is an object instance required

Comment: Are you trying to trigger it from a background task? That won't work, it needs to be triggered from an app that has foreground rights. You could trigger it just before your app goes away in the OnSuspended event.

Comment: Ok, so by doing some black magic I fixed the reference error, thanks for putting out that the ApplicationTrigger is quite important @StefanWickMSFT. I register the backgroundprogess in the UI, but call it in an Win32 Application. So now another process turns up on clicking on the NotificationTray (Systemtray, whatever). Next thing is when I now call the that same function with no UI, and try to call an toast message (that popup bottom-right) with that function inside, I get an "UnknownError in the toast message". How can I get more info or fix this?

Comment: OK, I didn't follow what you are saying. Maybe in your question you can clarify the scenario a bit more that you are trying to accomplish? If what you are really want is keep a process running in the Systray, you can follow this post: https://stefanwick.com/2017/06/24/uwp-app-with-systray-extension/